# How to synchronize a block of code to write whole words/lines to an output file while reading and writing char by char?

Tags: java

I have several input text files and I read from them to one output file. Each input file is being read in a separate thread. I would like to write whole words or lines to the output file. To write the whole content of input files I synchronize on FileWriter like this:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (fw) {
        int character;
        try {
            while ((character= fr.read()) != -1) {
                fw.write(character);    
            }           
            fw.write("\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

where fw is FileWriter and fr FileReader.

How to synchronize to write words or lines? I need to read and write character by character.

Example for words: file1: aaa bbb ccc; file2: AAA BBB CCC; file3: 11 222

output file:aaa AAA 11 bbb BBB 222 ccc CCC

Comment: are you looking for a specific output order in the output file?

Comment: You need to be holding the lock only until you hit a word boundary or end of line character and then releasing it so your other threads get a chance to write,

Comment: So I can't do this using synchronised block but rather using locks?

Comment: synchronized(someobject) is 'acquiring a lock'

Comment: then how to release this object when I hit the word boundry? can you give me an example?

Comment: basically you need to get out of the synchronized block to release the lock. you'll probably need two loops and a flag and/or use break. the outer loop keeps running the inner loop as long as there is data. inside the outer loop you grab the lock, read and write char by char until you hit word or line boundary and then drop the lock. this gives your other threads a chance to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get what you want by modifying

```
(character= fr.read()) != -1)
```

by testing for any of your delimiters.  When you read a white space from file, you break out of the while loop.  You will also want another while loop around the synchronized block, so that your run method repeatedly tries to acquire the lock, but allows other threads in as well.

```
public void run() throws IOException {
    boolean reading = true;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    while(reading) {   
        int character = fr.read();
        if(character == -1) {   
            reading = false;
            character='\n';
        }   
        buffer.append((char)character);
        if (character == ' ' || character == '\t' || character == '\n') {
            synchronized(fw) {
                fw.write(buffer.toString()); 
            }
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
        }           
    }
}
```

However note that you are synchronizing on both reading and writing.  As the read is in the synchronized block, only one thread will be reading from file at a time.  A better design would be for each thread to buffer up the characters read and then write out the whole word.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a FileReader to read byte by byte you can use a StringTokenizer to read from the input files. It allows you to read an entire word at a time. That way every time you write to your output file you are writing a word.

EDIT: Since you need to read byte by byte then here is my suggestion.

Use a StringBuffer to hold your characters until you get to a space. When you hit a space then you write out the contents of the StringBuffer and clear it. See code below:

```
public void run() {
    int character;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while ((character= fr.read()) != -1) {
            if(character == ' '){
                synchronized (fw){
                    fw.write(buffer.toString());
                }
                buffer.setLength(0);//Clears the buffer
            }
            else{
                buffer.append(character);
            }
        }  
        synchronized (fw){
            fw.write("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is still wrong since there is no concurrency here - you just grab the lock and hold onto it while the entire file is read and written.

Comment: You're still writing a word of buffer at a time. To fix this, you can't have StringBuffer and you can't have sb.append

Comment: If he has 3 input files then he has 3 threads each having their own copy of the code above. Therefore there are 3 StringBuffers at play. They all have the same FileWriter which is why it has to be synchronized but they have their own FileReaders since they all point to different files.

Comment: It only writes from the first file, but I already have a solution, so thanks anyhow ;)